# Location of Flight Controller in drone (PX4 specific)

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller, px4

I have a question for experienced users of PX4. Can the flight controller be placed anywhere in the drone, as long as it is pointing in the right direction and the calibration is made in the correct turning directions , where the flight controller is off centered in all axis ?

My question is that for example in a quadcopter the flight controller is placed close to a motor, pointing towards direction, calibrated on how the drone will turn, but very offset of the center, can the flight controller handle it ? (PX4 flight stack)